# How to design the Timescaledb schema for engineering data

Tags: postgresql, database-design, timescaledb

for a project in the engineering firm I work in, I want to leverage Timescaledb to store experiment results. 
I'm trying to figure out the db schema that will deliver the best read performances.
In my use case, I will be collecting several sensor logs for several experiments. For each experiment the time will start from 0.
From newbie thinking I think there are couple of options:

1- each experiment has its own table. The table will have as many columns as many sensors will be used. I bet, this is a terrible solution.

2- each sensor has its own table. I'm thinking to have 2 columns, value and an ID that identifies the experiment and the table name will be the sensor's name. In this table there will be many time duplicates since each experiment time starts from 0.

I'm not sure either of these solutions are actually going to be good.
What kind of schema should I use?

Thank you in advance,

Guido

Update1:
This is the schema I'm testing out right now:
[image]

After loading data from about 10 tests (a few hundreds of sensors logged at 100Hz) the Ch_Values table has 180M rows already and queries are terribly slow. I added indexes on ch_index, run_index, and time and now it's exponentially better. This is only ~10 tests tho. In reality, the db will contain hundreds of tests.
Any suggestion on how to efficiently store these data?

Comment: You're on the right track but not quite there yet. A combination of the 2 and an extension: 1 table with all experiments, 1 table with all sensors. Then an additional table experiment_sensors relating the experiment to the sensors. This table which contains the experiment id, the sensor id, experiment times, and perhaps sensor 'reading/measurements'. Without additional info I cannot take it any further, and specific requirements will change the picture. It should give you a starting point. Good luck!